# Comic: Astronaut trying to escape from alien planet

Tags: story-identification, comics

I remember reading a comic story in the early seventies which told the story of a stranded astronaut and his desperate attempts to escape from an alien planet and avoid aliens who were pursuing him. The aliens themselves would be best described as "mud" men as they looked vaguely human shaped but slightly formless.

The astronaut is terrified of these aliens and eventually manages to power up his rocket and make his escape though not long into his journey he struggles to breath and has to return to the planet.

It is then that as the aliens he dreaded approached he began to morph into one himself and come to the realisation that they are tranquil peaceful beings full of love and serenity able to communicate telepathically.

Comment: Hi! Can you add a little more information? Like, where was it published and in what language? (Even nUS vs. UK would limit the answers). Was it a short story in a larger magazine, a European style comic 'album', or a comic book spanning several issues? What it color or B&W?

Comment: Hello Klaus. I cant add much further information. It was a comic with the familiar format of pictures with speech bubble dialogue or thought. It was a story in a comic of many other stories. I read it as a child in the early seventies but it could easily have been from the late sixties as it was a comic in the class library read on rainy days when us kids were kept in doors. I seem to remember that the communication between the mud men was depicted by musical notes not language.